# Data part of Response is a long script instead of desired json object

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am building a web app using laravel and vuejs. I have made a axios get request to get a list of users . 
I am getting a Promise object, and from what i have read. Reason for getting a promise object is because it's an async request.

I have tried .then() to get data part of the response. But i am getting a huge script instead of desired data.

```
axios......then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
})
```

Initially what i did was

```
 var res = axios.get('/allUsers');
   console.log(res)
```

That time i came to know about promise object and read about. 
When i checked network in dev tools, status code is 200 and i can see list of users. So i guess my request is successfully completed.

What should be done to get the list of the users. That list i will be using to update my UI.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're getting back for data there are a few ways to handle this. You may need to convert the data after the you get receive the response.

```
axios.get('some_url')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        // do something with the data
    }).catch(err) {
        conosole.error(err);
    }
```

if you're seeing the data come through properly in the response and you're getting what you need without doing that then just do

```
axios.get('some url').then(res => {
  // do something in here with the data here
})
```

also make sure you're getting back json if that's what you're looking for. check your response to see if its html or json because they can be handled a bit differently

as an "Edit" you could also handle this with async await so you dont end up in callback hell

```
async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('some url');
      // next step might not be necessary
      const data = await res.json();
      // do something with the data
      console.log(data); // if converting it was necessary
      console.log(res); // if not converting
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
}
```